# Jquery : Replace All link depending cookie value and replace the true link after the click

Tags: jquery, cookies, hyperlink, click

I have a cookie value : clickotV

I have multiple href with the same class "t" :

- `<a href="link1.html" class="t">link1</a>`
- `<a href="link2.html" class="t">link2</a>`
- `<a href="link2.html" class="t"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>`

When cookie value is 1 :

- I must replace all href with the class "t" by out.php and add target `_blank`
  So i do this :

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if($.cookie('clickotV')==1){
          $("a.t").attr("href", "/out.php");
          $("a.t").attr("target", "_blank");
      }
  });
  ```
- But I must replace the link origin (without `_blank`) after user click on a replaced link (out.php)

How do I ?

Comment: So you need the original link back in after a click?  All links at once or one at a time?

Comment: Yes i need the original link back after the click

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remember data, then you will have to store it, fortunately, jQuery has the `.data()` command for this purpose.

The major problem you will have is getting the `href` to change *after* a click.  You could either bind the click event, set a short timeout to change the value back and unbind the click event after the default action.  Or try and open the page in javascript, but that is often blocked.

**Edit: Altered to reset all links on first click.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('clickotV') == 1) {
        $('a.t').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            self.data('old-href', self.attr('href'))
                .attr({ 'href': '/out.php',
                        'target': '_blank' });

            // Timeout - option 1
            self.click(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('a.t').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('old-href')).unbind('click');
                    });
                }, 10);

                // passthrough for default action
                return true;
            });

            // JS new-window - option 2
            self.click(function() {
                var newWindow = window.open(self.attr('href'), '_blank');

                $('a.t').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('old-href')).unbind('click');
                });

                newWindow.focus();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, i tryed. But the self click function works only in the link i clicked. So i need to have the original link on all links with the class "t" after a click.

Comment: @Piskorski Aurélien: I did ask you that explicitly, and you answered in the singular.  If you need all of them to change, then you will need to replace the `self` calls inside `.click()` with `$('a.t').each()` calls.

Comment: Hello,thanks you ! But can you correct your code because i am a big newbie with jquery. Thanks you for your patience

Comment: @Piskorski Aurélien: Amended as per your request.  Remember to only use one of the two blocks, *not both*.